# for in doesn't substract but for does

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, for-in-loop

I was on leetcode and I found a problem that I wanted to solve using `for in` instead of `if` about transforming a roman number to a natural number:

```
let s = "IV"
let res = 0
let dic = {
  M: 1000,
  D: 500,
  C: 100,
  L: 50,
  X: 10, 
  V: 5,
  I: 1
}
```

after setting the basic variables i made the actual code:

```
for (let i in s) {
  if (dic[s[i]] < dic[s[i + 1]]) {
    res -= dic[s[i]];
  } else {
    res += dic[s[i]];
  }
}
```

doing this the result it's 6 instead of 4 which i get surprised, if we take `i = 0`, we have that `if (1 < 5) {res -= 1}` then when `i = 1` will add 5 to -1 so the result should be 4.

after trying I found a way that did it exactly as I did but using `for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++)` and that worked.

My question is why does it work with another type of `for`? Is there a way to do it with `for in` as it is more readable?

Comment: `i` in `for... in` is a string, not an int.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a string. So use `parseInt` on it like so:

```js
let s = "IV"
let res = 0
let dic = {
  M: 1000,
  D: 500,
  C: 100,
  L: 50,
  X: 10, 
  V: 5,
  I: 1
}
for (let i in s.split("")) {
  if (dic[s[i]] < (dic[s[parseInt(i)+1]])) {
    res -= dic[s[i]];
  } else {
    res += dic[s[i]];
  }
}
console.log("res",res);
```